# #AskFirebase: how to get Firebase thumbnail images from storage in Angular (5)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Greetings: Thanks for all the Firebase videos. 
I'm using the Firebase cloud function that generates the thumbmail images (imageMagick). Works great. Now that this works I'd like to display them in my Angular (5) list. I have the URL reference to the original image (could be 4.mb each the thumbnails are 10kb).

At first though I thought the browser would just reference the same path with the 'thumb_' prefix but it appears that this does not work. If I make the folder public will this work? There appears to be different tokens for the original and thumb images. Is it possible to have the folder share the token this way the same token could get the original or thumb image.

I also attempted to use the downloadURL snapshot approach to download the thumbnail but there appears to be a timing issue and it's hit and miss and it works when the timing is right during form submission. It does take time to upload the image and then process into a thumbnail and the processes are decoupled.  I don't need the thumbnail immediately but for performance reasons I'd like to use the thumb for the actual viewing page. I've tried some of the tips to download but it hangs on the page. If there is an example of this where the cloud function can generate the thumbnail and post back the thumb url to the firestore reference that would be great. May need to use on create vs decoupled approach.

Any ideas would be great!

Thank you!
Matt
P.S. There appears to be different security approaches for storage, firestore and realtime databases. Any future release to make this easier or document so I can be sure data is secured properly. I do think firebase and new firestore is great for offline persistence and great for PWA development. :-)

Comment: Could you share the code you're working with and explain what's not working the way you expect?

Comment: I thought the same thing. now i am stuck lol